# Firebase Realtime Database GetValue(POJO.class) is not mapping the objects

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I was using `@PropertyName` inside POJO classes to map the firebase data.  After updating to new release `12.0.0`. The `@PropertyName` isn't working anymore as reported [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/fJ9Te3aNa9Q) .

Updated the POJO class [UserChatGroup.java](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PhFou-kb0Tf-ydb8h5X6mfjtuhRLhsiE/view?usp=sharing)

Firebase Data Schema is here  user_chat_groups->userIds-> List

Data Schema for [GroupItem is here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-ppdnkQJ6-0L6sFlYzarmJl97JA-sz3Q/view?usp=sharing)

I'm using ChildEventListener to get all user_chat_groups

```
DatabaseReference mDatabaseRef =FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("user_chat_groups").child(userId);
mDatabaseRef.addChildEventListener(childEventListener);

 ChildEventListener childEventListener = new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                try {
  //Map<String, Object> map = (Map<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
  //String groupName = (String) map.get("group_name");
  //String careproName = (String) map.get("carepro_name");
                    UserChatGroup chatGroup = dataSnapshot.getValue(UserChatGroup.class);
                    chatGroup.setKey(dataSnapshot.getKey());
                    completionHandler.onSuccess(chatGroup, FirebaseObserverType.CHILD_ADDED);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Exception " + e.getMessage());
                }
            } 
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    };
```

getValue returns me null  `GroupMember member = dataSnapshot.getValue(GroupMember.class);`

It works when I explicitly map the Object

```
Map<String, Object> map = (Map<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
String phone = (String) map.get("phone_number");
String name = (String) map.get("name");
```

When I try to go back to earlier Firebase version by changing all the firebase SDK verions to `11.2.2` e.g `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.2.2'` It still compiles against `12.0.0`

Comment: At first glance that first `GroupMember` looks fine. Can you edit to show the complete code that reproduces the problem? Specifically, I'd like to see a reference that you attach a listener to, and then how you read both `GroupMember` (which doesn't work) and directly access the members. It's also be really helpful to see the JSON (as text, no screenshots please) at the reference. You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks Frank for your comment. Just deleted my answer and I'm waiting for OP's code.

Comment: Do you absolutely need to be on 12.0.0?  You could just stay on 11.8.0 and wait for 12.0.1 to upgrade.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks for your reply. I've updated the question with data scheme and Firebase Listener details.

Comment: @DougStevenson When I try to go back to previous version `11.2.2` of Firebase SDK It still compiles on `12.0.0`. Is it because I've added `        google()` plug in on Top level Gradle file?. I've changed the firebase versions to `11.2.2` but that didn't help me as it throws error on `@PropertyName`. Is there any way to resolve this and  compile on `11.2.2`

Comment: As I said, the previous version is 11.8.0.  Not 11.2.2.  11.2.2 may have been *your* previous version, but 11.8.0 is the last version where PropertyName is not broken.

Comment: @DougStevenson thanks for  your reply.  I've tried updating firebase sdks to `11.8.0` it still throws me an error for `@PropertyName`

Comment: Then you're not really using 11.8.0 across the board.  Check all your dependencies again, and make sure they're *all* at 11.8.0, for all of Firebase and all of Play.